# Why can't we overload methods based on generic type of list

Tags: java, generics, overloading, erasure

I know that because of type erasure, all generic parameters are erased during compilation so if we have the following methods

```
public void addToList(List<Orange> list){}
public void addToList(List<Apple> list){}
```

They will both end up looking somewhat like this after type erasure

```
public void addToList(List list){}
```

And this is all understandable until you take into consideration that the compiler won't let you do this

```
public static void addToList(List<Orange> list){}
public static void main(String args[]){
      List<Apple> list = new Arraylist<>();
      addToList(list); //Error: passing a list of apples to a list of oranges
}
```

If we attempt to do something like this, the compiler won't let us, which means that the compiler knows the generic type of our lists. So I'm confused as to why the compiler is more than willing to throw errors at us, but pretends like it can't tell the difference between two overloaded methods?

Comment: That's the whole point of generics, to keep you from doing exactly that. The fact that the generic types are erased during compilation is an implementation detail, not something that you program "against".

Comment: To keep programmers from calling the proper version of overloaded methods?

Comment: "So I'm confused as to why the compiler is more than willing to throw errors at us, but pretends like it can't tell the difference between two overloaded methods?" The compiler *can* tell the difference. It's the runtime that can't.

Comment: Doesn't java resolve which overloaded method to pick during compile time?